# Trying to implement toggled sort by the column. If I parameterize the sortUsers function, I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded."

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

It works fine if I don't pass any parameter to the sortUsers and hardcode all the ".alltime" in the array sort. Then once parameterize the sortUsers function so that it will get the userType string parameter, I get the maximum call stack exceeded error.

Below is the code that works when without the parameter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      toggle: false
    }
    this.sortUsers = this.sortUsers.bind(this)
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent')
    .then(resp => this.setState({users: resp.data})
    )
}

  sortUsers(scoreType) {
    const before = this.state.users;
    const sorted = before.sort((a, b) =>
      this.state.toggle ?  b.alltime - a.alltime : a.alltime - b.alltime
    );
    this.setState({
      users: sorted,
      toggle: !this.state.toggle
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th onClick={this.sortUsers}>All Time</th>
            <th>Recent</th>
          </tr>
          {this.state.users.map((e, i) =>
            <tr>
              <td>{i +  1}</td>
              <td>{e.username}</td>
              <td><img src={e.img} width="20px"/></td>
              <td>{e.alltime}</td>
              <td>{e.recent}</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Below is the change that I have made when I pass a parameter into the sortUsers function.

```
sortUsers(scoreType) {
    const before = this.state.users;
    const sorted = before.sort((a, b) =>
      this.state.toggle ?  b[scoreType] - a[scoreType] : a[scoreType] - b[scoreType]
    );
    this.setState({
      users: sorted,
      toggle: !this.state.toggle
    });
  }

...

<th onClick={this.sortUsers("alltime")}>All Time</th>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will invoke your function automatically on render. That's why you are getting `maximum call stack size exceeded`. Your function gets called on `render` which causes `rerender` which again calls your function.

```
<th onClick={this.sortUsers("alltime")}>All Time</th>
```

Call it like this,

```
<th onClick={()=>this.sortUsers("alltime")}>All Time</th>
```